# Is there a way to decrease in counter_culture gem when using column_names?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, counter-cache

I need to decrease the counter of active users in a group, actually is increasing correctly when a new user pass from inactive to active in the group. But when change from active to inactive and then to active again the counter of active users is one more.

So what I need is to decrease the counter when passing from active to inactive.

Until now I tried to use the `delta_magnitude` param to make it decrease but didn't work.

### This is how it looks the class actually

```rb
class GroupUser < ApplicationRecord
    attr_accessor :send_challenge

    belongs_to :group
    belongs_to :user

    counter_culture :group, column_name: proc { |model| model.active? ? 'users_count' : nil },
                                   column_names: {
                                     ['group_users.active = ?', true] => 'users_count'
                                   }
```

As you can see I use the [dynamic-column-names](https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture#handling-dynamic-column-names)

### Here is what I have try so far

```rb
class GroupUser < ApplicationRecord
    attr_accessor :send_challenge

    belongs_to :group
    belongs_to :user

    counter_culture :group, column_name: proc { |model| model.active? ? 'users_count' : nil },
                                   column_names: {
                                     ['group_users.active = ?', true] => 'users_count'
                                   },
                                   delta_magnitude: 1
```

Here I add the [delta-magnitude](https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture#delta-magnitude) trying to make it decrease but didn't work.

I there a way to express a condition to make it decrease?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I just decrease it manually in the same query that change from active to inactive. If someone knows the correct answer it will be useful next time.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re updating the active attribute with normal save that includes callbacks, the current counter_culture version actually recalculate the count on value change.
As per the readme:

`Updates counter cache when values change, not just when creating and destroying`

At the reporting time that might have been a bug, but it should work now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is in a old project right now but I will tests if it works now in a new project that I'm currently working.

Comment: @JUANCAMPOS did you get a chance to try?

Comment: at the end I didn't have the chance to try it and recently I start using counter_cache for other projects and is working fine. Did you have problems recently?